# Best way to conditionally call a number of methods until a requirement is met

Tags: java

I have a series of methods and I want to call them consecutively until one of them returns a valid value, then skip the rest. My current code is like this:

```
String value = ""; //invalid value
while (true) {
  value = someMethod.getValue();
  if (value.length() > 0) break;
  value = someOtherMethod.getValue();
  if (value.length() > 0) break;
  value = yetAnotherMethod.getValue();
  break;
}
```

It's working fine, but I don't like the concept of creating an infinite loop and then manually breaking out of it. Is there a more elegant way to do this?

Comment: `someMethod.getValue()` is `someMethod().getValue()` because a method call have parenthesis, that important to know, to get a nice way to store them

Comment: Requests to review *working* code might be better sent to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ ... having said that: there is no way of not having an infinite loop. The only other thing I could see: if that pattern is really like this, you could be using a `List<java.util.Supplier>` that you fill with with lambdas like `() -> someMethod.getValue();`. Then, instead of doing ONE-IF-PER-METHOD, you only loop that list of suppliers...

Comment: Please precise the type of the objects your use, because at a moment `value` is a String, then it's an object that has `isValid` method

Comment: Yes, i edited my pseudocode in a hurry, the actual one is a bit different, it also has a few try-catch etc that I eliminated to make it shorter. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't (IMO) an elegant way.  But there are simpler ways than what you have written.  For example:

```
String value = someMethod.getValue();
if (value.length() == 0) {
    value = someOtherMethod.getValue();
}
if (value.length() == 0) {
    value = yetAnotherMethod.getValue();
}
```

In some contexts and for some variations of your problem, you may be able to craft a solution using a loop and an array of lambdas, or a stream, or similar.  However, that is going to involve overheads and boilerplate (and head scratching for the reader) ... and in my opinion that is NOT elegant.

Answer (score 1):

I think the Optional Class is a good way to show the "If this is not okay, then take that"-Intent.

```
Predicate<String> isNotEmpty = word -> word.length() > 0;

value = Optional.of(someMethod.getValue())
  .filter(isNotEmpty)
  .or(Optional.of(someOtherMethod.getValue())
  .filter(isNotEmpty)
  .orElse(yetAnotherMethod.getValue());
```

This looks a lot better if the `someMethod.getValue()` and `someOtherMethod.getValue()` methods return Optionals to express when no value is present.

```
value = someMethod.getValue()
  .or(someOtherMethod.getValue())
  .orElse(yetAnotherMethod.getValue());
```